# R confusion matrix error

Tags: r

I have to lists and I'm creating a confusion matrix like this

```
conf.mat <- table(x,y)
```

but the

```
accuracy <- sum(diag(conf.mat))/length(y) * 100)
```

is giving me 0 when I know for sure they aren't.

x is a long list that ends like this

```
[1546] data mining                              
25 Levels: clustering algorithms ...
```

and y ends like this

```
[1546] mixed discrete-continuous optimization                      
646 Levels:  access control ... world wide web
```

The thing is even though I assume diag(conf.mat) to contain 1546 it only contains 25 entries.

Any ideas what's happening? I assume it has something to do with the levels but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Yeah, but how can I have a matrix of 1546x1546. Basically every element in x vs every element in y? Thanks.